# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la descarga se refleje en el navegador, utilizando django-rest-framework extrayendo archivos de AWS S3?

Tags: django, aws, djangorestframework, amazon-s3

Tengo un inconveniente al descargar un archivo, pasa que estoy trabajando con django-rest-framework puedo descargar correctamente el archivo de un servidor S3 de AWS, pero el navegador no muestra la animación, estoy utilizando boto3.

class FileDowloadView(APIView):

```
def get(self,request):
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id = 'XXXXXXXXXSDDJSDA',
        aws_secret_access_key = 'JDDDDDDDDDDDDDXD',
    )
    s3 = session.resource('s3')
    s3.meta.client.download_file('XD',Itercionpdf,'C:/xxxx/Iterccion guia (1).pdf')
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi backend pude solucionar mi problema con el siguiente código en python.

```
def generarVista(nombreFile):
    client = boto3.client('s3',region_name = "aqui va la region")
    client.put_bucket_cors(Bucket = BUCKET_NAME,CORSConfiguration = 
    cors_configuration )

    url = client.generate_presigned_url(
                                    'get_object', 
                                     Params = { 
                                                'Bucket': BUCKET_NAME, 
                                                'Key': "prueba/"+nombreFile,                                                 
                   'ResponseContentDisposition':'attachment;prueba/'+nombreFile,
                   "ResponseContentType" : "application/pdf",
                   }, 
                                    ExpiresIn = 6000,)
    return url


cors_configuration = {
    'CORSRules': [{
        'AllowedHeaders': ['Authorization'],
        'AllowedMethods': ['GET'],
        'AllowedOrigins': ['*'],
        'ExposeHeaders': ['GET'],
        'MaxAgeSeconds': 3000
    }]
}
```

Y en mi front hice la petición de la siguiente manera.

```
const dowload = async (nameFile) =>{
    const response = await fetch(`ruta/${nameFile}/`,initParams())
    window.open(response.url,"_parent")
}
```